# PPTP VPN Setup on Debian based plug-computer

Tags: vpn

I have a sheevaplug Plug Computer running Debian taht I am trying to get a pptp VPN running on.

I have installed the pptp daemon and have it running and I can connect to it, but the IP address is not getting set properly and I cannot use the VPN to connect to the internet.

I have set the localip and the remoteip in my pptpd.conf file as follows:

localip 172.16.1.117 (which is the IP address of the sheevaplug)
remoteip 172.16.1.126-130

I have also set the net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 in sysctl.conf

However, whenever I connect to the VPN, the IP address of the connection is set to 192.168.0.1 (or something similar) and not to the, as I would expect, 172.16.1.xx address.  I think this is causing me not to be able to access the internet through this VPN, as well, since the IP address is not matching up.

Is there another configuration I need to setup to get this working properly?  Any info or nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by rebooting the plug computer.  It seemed from the instructions all I had to do was restart pptpd, but after a reboot, the IP was assigned correctly.

Now I just have to resolve a router port issue to get to it from the outside world.